# Binding each DropDownListFor within @foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

With my ASP.NET WebForms experience, this is my first MVC project.
Here's a problem that I don't think the mechanism allows, but I could be wrong.
Having a `DropDownListFor` within a `@foreach` is not that trivial.
First of all, the dropdown doesn't select the value I pass to it (`m => question.Answer`) -- notice in the image below they all show `No Answer`, because it didn't select the correct value I loaded it with.
Secondly, since they all end up with the same form-field name, how could the controller separate them back into the corresponding List<>?
I've been looking at this for an hour and searched for a similar example, but I can't find any.
What's a good solution that's not a hard-coded hack or a workaround?

Model:

```
public List<SelectListItem> PossibleAnswers
{
    get
    {
    return new List<SelectListItem>() 
    { 
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "No Answer", Value = "0" }, 
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Very Bad", Value = "1" }, 
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Bad", Value = "2" }, 
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Average", Value = "3" }, 
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Good", Value = "4" },
        new SelectListItem() { Text = "Very Good", Value = "5" } 
    };
    }
}
public enum SurveyAnswer
{
    NoAnswer,
    VeryBad,
    Bad,
    Average,
    Good,
    VeryGood
}
public class SurveyQuestionClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public SurveyAnswer Answer { get; set; }
}
public List<SurveyQuestionClass> QuestionsAnswers { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var question in Model.QuestionsAnswers)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => question.Answer, Model.PossibleAnswers, new { style = "font-size: small;" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Raw(question.Question)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use editortemplates

this can be applied as the following:

Move your possible answers to the SurveyQuestionClass. then you can specify an editortemplate like this:

```
@model SurveyQuestionClass

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Answer, Model.PossibleAnswers, new { style = "font-size: small;" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Raw(Model.Question)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Editortemplates are partialviews which should be placed in an EditorTemplates folder in your views folder. So if this applies to your home view, the template should be located in: views > Home > EditorTemplates.

Editortemplates should be named as type.cshtml. so in your case: SurveyQuestionClass.cshtml

in your view, this results in simply:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.QuestionsAnswers)
```

When you get your model back in the controller function, all questions and answers are being bound to the QuestionsAnswers List. Iterating through the list and reading the SurveyQuestionClass.Answer property, will give you the question answer