# How to create several DropDownListFor with a foreach-loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of a custom object and I want to create a dropdownlist for each of the objects in the list.

Relevant parts of my model looks like this:

```
public class ColorModel
{    
    public enum Colors
    {
        Blue,
        Red,
        Yellow,
        Green,
        Purple
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> Quantities
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, int>()
            {
                {"0", 0},
                {"1", 1},
                {"2", 2},
                {"3", 3},
                {"4", 4}
            };
        }
    }

    public List<AmountPerColor> ColorList { get; set; }

    public class AmountPerColor
    {
        public Colors Color { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ColorList is initiated as:

```
colorModel.ColorList = new List<ColorModel.AmountPerColor>()
{   
    new ColorModel.AmountPerColor() {Color = ColorModel.Colors.Blue, Amount = 4},
    new ColorModel.AmountPerColor() {Color = ColorModel.Colors.Red, Amount = 1},
    new ColorModel.AmountPerColor() {Color = ColorModel.Colors.Yellow, Amount = 0},
    new ColorModel.AmountPerColor() {Color = ColorModel.Colors.Green, Amount = 2},
    new ColorModel.AmountPerColor() {Color = ColorModel.Colors.Purple, Amount = 0}
};
```

View:

```
@{ var i = 0; }
@foreach (var color in Model.ColorList)
{
    <label>@color.Color</label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ColorList[i].Amount, new SelectList(Model.Quantities, "key", "value", Model.ColorList[i].Amount), new { @name = @color.Color, @id = @color.Color })
    i++;
}
```

This is wrapped in a Html.BeginForm along with some other parameters and sent to the following controller-method:

```
public ActionResult Action(ColorModel colorModel)
{
    //do controller stuff
}
```

Problem is in the controller, the colorList has the correct amounts in the correct order, by the value of the Color-property is defaulted to "0" for every entry. I tried to change enum to a string instead and the property was now null for every entry. Also tried using an EditorTemplate as suggested by the answer to this question: [Binding each DropDownListFor within @foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776179/binding-each-dropdownlistfor-within-foreach). However, the property was still 0 or null.

How do I maintain the Color-property when I retrieve the model in the controller?

Comment: seems you just mixed key and value up, your amount is int and your key is string, try to switch it and tell us the result

Comment: How many dropdowns do you need? More than one? In that case the controller should accept a `List<ColorModel>` object

Comment: What is the html rendered by your `@Html.DropDownListFor` method?

Comment: @fuchs777 Do you the quantities-dictionary? That is just for generating the SelectList in the view.

Comment: @theghostofc Yes, but the model already has a list corresponding for each of the dropdowns. I don't see why I would need a separate model for every dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the DropDownListFor was only bound to the Amount-property. To keep the Color-property I had to add this under the DropDownlistFor

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ColorList[i].Color)
```

After that line of code the Color-property was set correctly for every entry in ColorList.